# Include text between check boxes in a check box group?

Tags: checkbox, xpages

Anyone know if there's a way to include some text between check boxes in a check box group in XPages?  What I'd like to do is implement something like this with a single check box group:

Explanation about these checkboxes:
- Checkbox 1
- Checkbox 2

Explanation about these checkboxes:
- Checkbox 3
- Checkbox 4

Comment: Are you looking to have a checkbox group with 2 columns and 2 rows with a label in front of each row?

Comment: No - I was looking to have some text followed by a couple checkboxes followed by more text and more checkboxes.  Unfortunately, the formatting in my question didn't quite come out right.

Comment: Any reason in particular why you are looking at a checkbox group instead of using a bunch of single checkbox controls bound together using the controls' grouping properties?

Comment: This would make an excellent candidate for a custom control: supply a json structure and the control renders the checkboxes as you like them.

Comment: @LotharMueller - can you expand on the "controls' grouping properties"?  Not seeing any obvious check box properties to bind together individual check boxes.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: I read and wrote "Checkbox" but thought "Radio Button" where we can group the singular radio elements. What I meant is: is there a reason why you don't just use plain singular checkbox controls instead of groups? What is the use case you are thinking about?

Comment: I'd like to store the checkbox values in a multi-value field, as you can do with a checkbox group.  Not sure how to accomplish that with individual checkboxes.  Is there a way to bind multiple checkboxes to a single field/datasource?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there isn't an easy solution to this using the CheckboxGroup control. You'll have to build it one checkbox at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have multiple checkbox groups, then on an onchange you can change the value of another group to null.